# Matrices: Further Pure 1 Question 8 (June 2013)

Tags: matrices

Question Paper
http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP1-QP-JUN13.PDF
Mark Scheme
http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP1-WS-MS-JUN13.PDF

For those that cannot open these links I will write down the coordinates of the triangles instead.

8 The diagram shows two triangles T1 and T2

T1 (1, 1), (1, 2) and (3, 1)
T2 (1, 3), (1, 6) and (3, 3)

(a) Find the matrix which represents the stretch that maps triangle T1 onto triangle T2.

What is meant by the word "maps"? The matrix which moves the triangle as well as stretches it? Or just the matrix which stretches it?

(b) The triangle T2 is reflected in the line y=sqrt(3)x to give a third triangle, T3. Find, using surd forms where appropriate:

(i) the matrix which represents the reflection that maps triangle T2 onto triangle T3;

(ii) the matrix which represents the combined transformation that maps triangle T1 onto triangle T3

What is a combined transformation?

If anyone knows anything about the mark scheme and what you get the marks for (method, accuracy, etc) could you include information? Also show all working please and any termonology linked with this question would be awesome. If anyone knows of any youtube videos too which teach specifically about this subject would be a life saver, thanks regards Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for part (a) you need a vertical  stretch. so $Tx = x, Ty = 3y$ should do. the matrix representation of $T$ is $$A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&3}.$$

(b) the transformation reflecting on a mirror along the line $y = \sqrt 3 x$ is represented by the matrix 
$$B = \pmatrix{-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} & \frac{1}{2}} $$ you can get the vertices of the triangle $T_3$ by computing $B *vertex$  for example, the point $(3,3)$ will go to  $\pmatrix{-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} & \frac{1}{2}}\pmatrix{3\\3} = \frac{3}{2}\pmatrix{\sqrt 3 - 1\\\sqrt 3 + 1}.$

(c) the combined transformation is given by the matrix $BA$